# At a dataframe how to explode a column with a list (with same length at all rows) into different columns at the same row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, explode

I have following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1','2', '3'], 'List': [['a1','a2'], ['b1','b2'], ['c1','c2']]})

Out[18]: 
   A      List
0  1  [a1, a2]
1  2  [b1, b2]
2  3  [c1, c2]
```

I would like to explode the column *List* into two new columns (*L1* and *L2*) at the same row.

```
   A  L1  L2
0  1  a1  a2
1  2  b1  b2
2  3  c1  c2
```

Which would be the fastest way to do it?

It would be great to assign also the names for the columns at the same time (L1 and L2).

Thank you in advance and best regards,

Pablo G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df[['A']].join(df['List'].apply(pd.Series, index=['L1', 'L2']))
```

Comment: @CypherX always useful to check what pd.Series takes :)

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Try this: **`pd.concat` + `df[col].apply(pd.Series)`**

```py
# Option-1
pd.concat([df['A'], df['B'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'L1', 1: 'L2'})], axis=1)

# Option-2
# credit: Mark Wang; for suggestion on using, index = ['L1', 'L2']
pd.concat([df['A'], df['B'].apply(pd.Series, index=['L1', 'L2'])], axis=1)
```

[image]

### If you want to keep only the columns `L1` and `L2`

```py
# Option-1
df['B'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'L1', 1: 'L2'})

# Option-2
# credit: Mark Wang; for suggestion on using, index = ['L1', 'L2']
df['B'].apply(pd.Series, index=['L1', 'L2'])
```

### If you want to keep all the original columns

```py
# with prefix
pd.concat([df, df['B'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f'B_')], axis=1)

# with user given column-names
pd.concat([df, df['B'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'L1', 1: 'L2'})], axis=1)
```

**Logic**:

- Concat `df` and `df_expanded` along the columns (`axis=1`).
- Where, `df_expanded` is obtained by doing `df[col].apply(pd.Series)`. 
  This expands the lists into columns.
- I added a `.add_prefix('B_')` to add clarity on where the columns originated from (column `B`).

### Example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 
                   'B': [['11', '12'], 
                         ['21', '22'], 
                         ['31', '32']]
                   })
col = 'B'
pd.concat([df, df[col].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f'{col}_')], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works great. Is there an additional paramenter to remove column 'A'?

Comment: If you want only columns `L1` and `L2`, then don't do the concat. Just `df['B'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'L1', 1: 'L2'})` should do the job.

Comment: Thans to your comments with further investigations I tryed this: `df[['L1','L2']]=df['B'].apply(pd.Series)` and it works.

Comment: Yes, that is because it assigns the created columns to two new columns in df. You can do these things in a lot of different ways. It’s up to the user to decide how he/she would choose to do so.